# Not able to extend Less mixin

Tags: css, less, mixins, less-mixins

I would like to have below CSS output using Less

```
.selected-values,
.selected-values a {
    background-color: #505050;
    color: #fff;
}

.selected-values {
    display: block;
}

.selected-values a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So far i have thought of below Less syntax, but it is not working.

```
.selected-dropdown-values() {
    background-color: #505050;
    color: #fff;
}

.selected-values:extend(.selected-dropdown-values) {
    display: block;
}

.selected-values a:extend(.selected-dropdown-values) {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I am not able to apply any `extend` logic to generate this syntax. I might be missing something or i am unaware about how to do it properly in Less. Also, I do not want `.selected-dropdown-values` mixin to output in CSS.

Comment: please share your problem in jsfiddle

Comment: Currently you cannot extend mixins. You would have to remove the `()` in the first rule. Or if you don't want the `.selected-dropdown-values` to come in the output, then you may have to put those properties to the base class itself.

Comment: @Archana sorry, but i am not aware about any LESS fiddle. If you can point me to someplace like that, it would be awesome and i can setup a LESS fiddle.

Comment: @Harry, can you please show me some example of base class. I would be happy to know more about it.

Comment: @khagesh: As far as I am aware JSfiddle doesn't support Less (unless included as an external resource). CodePen and CSSDeck does provide Less support, but for this particular problem I don't think demo is required.

Comment: @khagesh: Sure can, but just one question before that. Are you trying to make the `display:block` apply only for `.selected-values` and not for `.selected-values a`? If yes, that might be a bit tricky.

Comment: @Harry: yes, boss. You are absolutely correct. I have other properties as well that i will add in later, but i would definitely like to have this kind of structure in CSS. Thank you for your time . :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60666/discussion-between-harry-and-khagesh).

Comment: Speaking of JSfiddle, it does support Less with just a little trick: follow the [white rabbit](http://jsfiddle.net/t2xe9/) (there's newer version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/seven_phases_max/hb2rsm2x/) - but I did not yet test it deeply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments and discussed in the chat, Less currently does not support extending of mixins (there is a request and it might get addressed in v2.0.0 or later). (**Note:** To be more precise with wordings, extending of mixins which are not output in CSS is not supported.)

So, the best way forward would be to do the below:

**Less:**

```
.selected-dropdown-values { // just remove the braces
    background-color: #505050;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Just remove the braces from the `.selected-dropdown-values` rule. Ofcourse this would cause that rule also to be present in the CSS output but given that we are using `extend`, it would mean only one extra line in CSS output.

**Output:**

```
.selected-dropdown-values,
.selected-values,
.selected-values a {
    background-color: #505050;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank @Harry, i guess i would have to compromise on that extra line. :)